# How can I have 2 different mod folders with the new Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-launcher

I like playing Equivalent Exchange 2 mod, which was only updated for 1.2.5.  It was also an external mod, meaning it was put in the "mods" folder.  The new launcher works great, but I cannot find a way to manage the mods in the mods folder based on the profiles I want to play.

So what I want is to have a "Skytable" version that runs EE2 and a few other external mods, and also have a "Tekkit" version that has a custom layout of mods, some of which are external.  Both are on the 1.2.5 base Minecraft, but I don't want mods from Skytable to work on Tekkit and vise versa.

Is there a way to have the "profiles" the launcher creates look in a subfolder of "mods" for something like '/mods/"Profile name" for external mods? I know moderate Java programming, but have never looked at the code for Minecraft or any mods and etc.

Comment: @Timelord64 Oh look, a recent question about an outdated version.....and I thought I was the only person who didn't update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I go around it is by having separate sub-folders for each profile I use in my .Minecraft directory. For example, I have a folder called **'profiles'** which stores the different profile directories which can differ depending on the version or whether or not I use mods. Thus, each different profile I have in the launcher is configured to its respective directory.

*For example:* Say you had a Forge profile for modded Minecraft, you'd configure the *Game Directory* to be in **.minecraft\profiles\Forge**, and thus the mods folder for that would be there. Then you could have a separate folder for Vanilla or whatever (**.minecraft\profiles\Vanilla**) and have a different profile configured to that. You could even divide a folder in **profiles** further to separate different versions. The whole system is seamless.

*(To configure your game directory, select your desired profile and click "Edit Profile". You should see the option to modify the directory.)*

Comment: Are you referring to setting the *Game Directory* path in the Profile Editor of the launcher? If so, please try to make that more clear. Ideally, you could provide a sort of tutorial, too.

Comment: @MrLemon I'll make an edit to reflect on that.

Comment: After a year, I finally freaking figured out what you were talking about, and it is a G

Comment: ... God send.  Hit enter too early

Comment: @Lightfire228 Glad this helped you!

Comment: This saved me from being lynched by a 7yo.  Thank you.  I do wonder, though, whether the saves folder should be in each profile folder...

Comment: @RobM 'saves' folders should be - and normally are - separate per profile. loading a save from a modded profile to a purely vanilla profile for example wouldn't retain anything that comes from any mods.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/) which loads multiple instances of Minecraft, each stored in separate folders. It also supports Forge integration.

---

I would recommend using a Modpack Launcher. Most (all?) allow you to custom create modpacks or modify existing mod packs. They also allow you to custom create your own 'modpacks' or grouping of mods. They store these in separate folders, mods and configs.

To use them, just create an empty mod pack and drop in mods to the appropriate mod folder for the pack. Most have an option from within the launcher to do this for you. They also provide the ability to enable/disable individual mods which makes testing very easy.

Check out:

- [Technic](http://www.technicpack.net/download)
- [Feed the Beast](http://www.feed-the-beast.com/)
- [Curse](http://beta.cursevoice.com/games/minecraft)

Answer (score -3):

There is an add-on to the default minecraft launcher that manages .minecraft/mods with different profiles. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/2488030-launcher-win-mac-lin-extendable-minecraft

Comment: How would someone go about using this mod to accomplish what is being asked for?